# sorting temp array without impacting main array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to sort temporary array (`tempArr`) in method  in order to display `k` values but I want the main array (`array`) to stay unsorted. For some reason I dont understand when I do this `tempArr=array;` and then use only `tempArray` in while loop array is being sorted aswell. What is the reason?

```
public static void kLargestNums(int[] array, int k) {
    int[] tempArr;
    tempArr = array;
    int liczba;
    int a;

    do {
        liczba = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tempArr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (tempArr[i] < tempArr[i + 1]) {
                a = tempArr[i];
                tempArr[i] = tempArr[i + 1];
                tempArr[i + 1] = a;
                liczba++;
            }
        }
    } while (liczba != 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        System.out.println(tempArr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `tempArr=array` is not creating a copy. You just have your variable `tempArr` point at the same Array as `array` with that line of code.

Comment: try replacing with this: tempArray = array.clone();

Answer (score 0):

Because `tempArr=array` sets the pointer of `tempArr` to point to the same place in memory where `array` sits.

Answer (score 0):

In java assigning one object to another doesn't copy the values of the object. It points both handles to the same object.
If you want to copy values you can use the funcion clone()

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of reference Id. Because both are carrying the same reference id.
You can use clone method of Object class.

Something like
int[] tempArr = array.clone();